# Update price in checkout page without refresh Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript, price, controllers

I have a controller where I apply some discount on the checkout page.
Now, I can see the price change just after I refresh the page.

I search for a solution, to refresh the price using a Js file.

```
define([
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-totals'
        ], function ($, getTotalsAction) {
        "use strict";

          $.ajax({
                method: "post",
                url: demoUrl, //your ajax Url
                data: {/*here post data*/},
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (resp) {
                   //below two lines refershing cart summary
                    var deferred = $.Deferred();
                    getTotalsAction([], deferred); //this function already created in Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-totals.js file
                }

            });

});
```

But if I insert this script in my controller, nothing happens!

Does anyone have any idea how can an update the price without refreshing the page?

I know by default Magento 2 has a function to do that. When I enter a valid coupon code the price it's updated without refreshing the page!

Comment: Hi. Did you achieve this?

Comment: Hi, yes, but i achieved this using jQuery

Comment: could you please share me your solution?

Comment: Could you please share your solution with us?

Comment: Share your ajax call file (entire js file) so i can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use sections.xml in following location vendor/module_name/etc/frontend/sections.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
    <action name="route/controller/actionname">
        <section name="cart"/>
        <section name="checkout-data"/>
    </action>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

The order total summary should be reloaded after applying the custom coupon. We should add the event handle function for the custom form, for example: onclick, onchange. We can follow the logic of coupon form.

The coupon form:

[image]

We can find the click event handle function: `vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/discount.js`

```
     apply: function() {
            if (this.validate()) {
                isLoading(true);
                setCouponCodeAction(couponCode(), isApplied, isLoading);
            }
        },
```

---

There is a note: we should use `mage/storage,` -> `lib/web/mage/storage.js` to perform asynchronous POST, GET, PUT, DELETE request to server. For example: `vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/view/frontend/web/js/action/set-coupon-code.js`

Comment: Please help with http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/166641/magento-2-update-quote-cart-value-after-advanced-pricing-changed

Answer (score 0):

the checkoutData is stored in the localStorage of the browser and is refreshed on specific actions.

you should read the devdocs article about FPC holepunching here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cache/cache-priv-priv.html

to refresh the checkout data object you have to define a section upgrade for your ajax call like here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/etc/frontend/sections.xml#L33

note that this update (like described in the devdocs) will only trigger on POST or PUT requests.

magento should then fire a sections update request for the checkout data section right after your ajax call completed successfully

Answer (score 0):

If u have Controller then u must have ajax function inside custom js . so in response of that ajax call use below two lines.

```
 var deferred = $.Deferred();
 getTotalsAction([], deferred);
```

And for this you must create object i.e getTotolsAction as shown in your question code inside your custom js.

Note : Don't use JS code inside controller, won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I use this approach:

```
require(['Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-totals'], function(a) { a([]); } );
```