# Magento 2: Admin price changes are not refreshing minicart immediately till checkout

Tags: magento2, cart, event-observer, custom, magento2.1.5

I have added 1 product with it's price in Cart. It's value is 100 USD.

Now from backend I'm enabling Special Price & set it to 50 USD.

[image]

How can I directly apply that price in Cart? I know we can use Observer `controller_action_catalog_product_save_entity_after` after Admin Product Save & update `quote_item` table.

But it should be until checkout Whatever Paypal/Bank Transfer payment gateway.

I'm also changing price Group Wise/Tier pricing as well. Need to manage Group Wise Pricing & Special Price as well.

What is the best way to achieve this & how?

How to apply any price change like Special/Tier Price Immediately on Frontend for logged in or not logged in user who previously have that product in cart?

**Strange**: In Wordpress WooCommerce this case works fine.