# Magento 2: Update Minicart

Tags: magento2, event-observer, price, mini-cart, magento2.1.5

I need to update minicart from Homepage to Untill Checkout.

I exactly need to update price to solve [Magento 2: Admin price changes are not refreshing minicart immediately till checkout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/166641/magento-2-admin-price-changes-are-not-refreshing-minicart-immediately-till-chec)

Which event I need to use?

I already seen

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-events.html
https://webkul.com/blog/update-mini-cart-magento2/