# Magento 2: Update Minicart Product Price

Tags: magento2, price, quote, mini-cart, magento2.1.5

I would like to update Minicart Product's price.

I need all parameters so we can update it.

It should update automatically Grand & Sub Total or We need to Update as well?

Comment: When and  from where you   want update price?

Comment: Hi @AmitBera Need to solve http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/166641/magento-2-admin-price-changes-are-not-refreshing-minicart-immediately-till-chec Lastly need to work on `controller_action_predispatch` event. Please give ur inputs